# A C++ construct which improves readability, evaluates to nothing but is NOT a macro

Tags: c++, templates, readability, api-design

I have the following situation. We are writing a library which has a class which has a lot of fields (majority) of it depending on some optional fields which have "flags" (bits in a number basically) if the optional field is present or not.

The fields of the class are required to be public for easier access (I know it's bad), and 3rd party developers will read the header files (beside of their documentation) in order to get familiar with the structure and the connection of various fields to their corresponding options.

The problem is, the customer wants to make easy for their developers to identify which fields depends on which optional structure with as little effort as possible.

One of the solutions is to put a comment above or after the field (class member) name telling it uses this option field. This is the basic choice.

However the class is already over populated with around 500 members (fields) so I don't know that if adding extra 500 lines, or long comments will add to the quality of it.

We came up with the following constructs:

```
#define DEPENDS
#define ON
#define BIT(x) ((x)-1)
#define OF(x)

struct source{};

struct options 
{
    options(const source&) {}
};

template <int BITIDX>
struct optional
{
    optional(const options&) {}
};

struct something
{
    // this constructor will be implemented in the CPP
    // so the user  (developer) will not see it
    something (const source& src) :
      msource(src), initial_options(src), other_options(src), 
      field1(initial_options), field2(other_options) {}

    options initial_options;
    options other_options;

    optional<DEPENDS ON BIT(1) OF (initial_options)>   field1;
    optional<DEPENDS ON BIT(1) OF (other_options)  >   field2;

    source msource;
};

int main()
{
    source s;
    something a(s);
}
```

but obviously this is not much better due to namespace pollution, macros, etc ...

So, the question: is there a better way to achieve our goal to provide a meaningful way of presenting the connection of a field from a bit of an option?

(Please note, C++11 class member initialization is **NOT** allowed, otherwise I would not ask this question :) We have to stick to older compilers :( )

Comment: You're mostly there, and don't need the macros: just enumerate your flags, and either merge your two optional fields for simplicity, or use two template params (one indicating which field to use, and one which bit inside that field).

Comment: @Useless I cannot merge any two fields. The data comes in in a long bitstream and these fields are not adjacent to each other. Something like: fields, fields, options (1), optional fields depending on options 1, optional options (2) depending on options 1, fields, fields, optional fields depending on optional options (2) etc  ...

Also, could you provide a little bit of code sample? Thanks!

Comment: I didn't mean merging _data_ fields, I meant merging the _flags_ fields that indicate which optional data fields are present. We need better terminology for this. Anyway, you can see what I mean in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct something
{
    enum OptionGroup { Initial, Other /*...*/ };
    enum InitialFields { A, B /*...*/ };
    enum OtherFields { X, Y /*...*/ };
```

So, we enumerated the fields A,B etc. inside each optional group. Since they're zero-based and incrementing, the enumerated values will tell us which bit represents each field.

```
    template <typename TYPE, OptionGroup GROUP, int BIT>
    struct Optional {
        TYPE val;
        operator TYPE& () { return val; }
        operator TYPE const& () const { return val; }
    };
```

This records the group of an optional field, and which bit within that group represents it. You didn't say what the type of your fields is, so I made it generic. You also didn't say how you initialize them, so it might need constructors etc.

```
    int mandatory1;
    int initialOptions;
    Optional<int, Initial, A> a;
    Optional<int, Initial, B> b;
    int otherOptions;
    Optional<double, Other, X> x;
```

And here we have the actual storage for a sequence of mandatory and optional fields.

now, we need some way to get the flags for each group:

```
    template <OptionGroup GROUP> int getGroupFlags();
```

with that, we can check whether a given field is valid ...

```
    template <typename TYPE, OptionGroup GROUP, int BIT>
    bool isValid(Optional<TYPE,GROUP,BIT> const &field) {
        return getGroupFlags<GROUP>() & (1 << BIT);
    }
};
```

Sadly, recording the association between the enumeration and the group is still manual (this is where being able to merge both sets of option flags into a single bit field would have made life easier)

```
template <> int something::getGroupFlags<something::Initial>() { return intialOptions; }
template <> int something::getGroupFlags<something::Other>() { return otherOptions; }
```

This could be cleaned up considerably (eg, by binding each optional group into a single struct instead of hard-coding the nasty OptionGroup->flag field relationship), but this seems like the least work.